# Chrome extension opening too many tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For some reason, when I click the extension icon, my extension (which is supposed to open a tab) will do just that at first, but the second time I click it, it will open an additional 2 tabs. The third time, it opens an additional 3 tabs. So after clicking this extension icon 3 times I should have 3 new tabs, but instead I have 6. Any ideas? (this is a simplified version of my extension)

background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
    console.log("worked so far");
  });


  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if( request.type === "copy" ) {
        console.log(request.url)
        chrome.tabs.create({"url": request.url});

      }
    }
  );
});
```

content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"type":"copy","url" : "http://www.google.com"});
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Seems you are adding the listener again each time, hence the amount of new tabs opening directly corresponding to the number of time you run your action.

Comment: try to move the onMessage listener outside of the onClicked listener.

Comment: @Stuart and vaku thank you!

Comment: There's also no need for chrome.tabs.query: just use `tab.id` instead of `activeTab.id`.